復元抽出と非復元抽出を切り替えて実行できる関数を定義したい
targetに格納されている値について、population内からこれに近似した値とindexを出力したいです。
抽出方法は復元抽出と非復元で、抽出関数の中で方法を切り替えたいと思っています。
以下のコードは、復元抽出だけ可能です。
% python
Python 3.9.12

>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
>>> print(pd.__version__)
1.4.2
>>> target = pd.DataFrame([1, 1, 1, 2], columns=['探索する値'])
>>> population = pd.DataFrame([1, 1, 2], columns=['探索先'])
>>> print(target, '\n', population)
   探索する値
0      1
1      1
2      1
3      2 
    探索先
0    1
1    1
2    2
>>> def match(target, population, m='復元'):
...     # 最近傍法探索
...     neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1, metric='euclidean')
...     neigh.fit(np.array(population).reshape(-1, 1))
...     
...     #　ユークリッド距離と探索先のインデックス
...     distances, indexes = neigh.kneighbors(np.array(target).reshape(-1, 1))
...     
...     match_df = pd.DataFrame({'match_indexes': indexes.reshape(-1),
...                              'match_distances': distances.reshape(-1)})
...     match_df = pd.merge(target, match_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
...     
...     return m, match_df
... 
>>> method, df = match(target, population, '復元')
>>> print(f'{method}抽出法', '\n', df)
復元抽出法 
    探索する値  match_indexes  match_distances
0      1              0              0.0
1      1              0              0.0
2      1              0              0.0
3      2              2              0.0

関数を改善し、引数mが非復元の場合、以下の出力を得るにはどのようにコードを変更すれば良いでしょうか。
非復元抽出法
    探索する値  match_indexes  match_distances
0      1              0              0.0
1      1              1              0.0
3      2              2              0.0

非復元抽出の場合、targetのインデックス1はインデックス0と重複しますが、populationのインデックス1に値があるため残したいです。
一方、targetのインデックス2はインデックス0や1と重複するため出力結果からは除外したいです。
なお、実データの2つのデータフレームはそれぞれ数十万レコードあるため、極力for文を使わず、またNearestNeighborsによって距離を計算したいと考えています。
上記2つのサンプルデータは完全一致しますが、実データにおいては完全一致するとは限らないため、任意の幅の中に収まった値をマッチさせています。

最終的にPandasをループで回さず、numpy化して処理しました。
def matching_score(target, population, method):
    """
        最近傍法により近似したスコアを探索し、見つかったらそのindexと距離をDataFrame化して返す
        復元抽出・非復元抽出によって返す値を変える

        Parameters
        ----------
        target : pd.Series
            検索対象データ（インデックス,検索値）
        population : pd.Series
            検索先データ（インデックス,検索値）
        method : str
            抽出方法指定(復元/非復元)

        Returns
        -------
        result_df : pd.DataFrame
            index : int
                検索対象インデックス番号
            score : float
                検索対象スコア
            match_index : int
                ヒットしたインデックス番号
            match_distance : float
                検索対象とヒットしたスコアの距離
    """
    result_df = pd.DataFrame()
    
    if method == '復元':
        neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1, metric='euclidean')
        neigh.fit(np.array(population).reshape(-1, 1))

        #　ユークリッド距離と探索先のインデックス
        distances, indexes = neigh.kneighbors(np.array(target).reshape(-1, 1),
                                              return_distance=True)
        _distances = distances.reshape(-1)
        _indexes = indexes.reshape(-1)
        
        result_df = pd.DataFrame({'match_index': population.iloc[_indexes].index,
                                  'match_distance': _distances})
        result_df.index = target.index 
        result_df = pd.merge(target, result_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)

    elif method == '非復元':
        
        # 探索する値のユニーク値と頻度を取得
        target_ps, target_count = np.unique(target, return_counts=True)
        # pd.Seriesをnumpy化
        target_arr = np.concatenate(
                                    [np.array(target.index).reshape(1, -1),
                                     target.to_numpy().reshape(1, -1)]
                                    ).T
        population_arr = np.concatenate(
                                    [np.array(population.index).reshape(1, -1),
                                     population.to_numpy().reshape(1, -1)]
                                    ).T
        # 結合する配列(1x4)を初期化
        result_arr = np.array([[-1, None, None, None]]).reshape(1, 4)
        
        # プログレスバーの合計値を設定
        bar = tqdm(total=len(target_ps))
        
        for _target_ps, _target_count in zip(target_ps, target_count):
            
            # プログレスバーの進捗
            bar.update(len(target_arr[target_arr[:, 1]==_target_ps]))

            neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=_target_count, metric='euclidean')
            neigh.fit(population_arr[:, 1].reshape(-1, 1))

            #　ユークリッド距離と探索先のインデックス
            distances, indexes = neigh.kneighbors(target_arr[target_arr[:, 1]==_target_ps][:, 1].reshape(-1, 1),
                                                  return_distance=True)

            # 距離の最小値のみに絞込み、そのインデックスを保持
            _distances = distances[0][np.where(distances[0] == distances[0].min())]
            _indexes = indexes[0][np.where(distances[0] == distances[0].min())]

#             # 横方向に配列を結合
            match_arr = (np.concatenate([
                        target_arr[target_arr[:, 1]==_target_ps][:len(_indexes), :], # 探索元のインデックスとスコアを絞り込み、距離の最小値を持つレコード分だけに絞込み
                        population_arr[_indexes][:, 0].reshape(-1, 1), # マッチング先のインデックス
                        _distances.reshape(-1, 1), # 最小距離
                        ], axis=1))
    
            # 縦方向に配列を結合
            result_arr = np.concatenate([result_arr[result_arr[:, 0]>-1], match_arr], axis=0)
            
            # 探索先で使ったインデックスのレコードを探索先から削除する
            population_arr = population_arr[~(np.isin(population_arr[:, 0], match_arr[:, 2])), :]

        result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_arr[:, 1:],
                                 index=result_arr[:, 0].astype('int64'),
                                 columns=['score', 'match_index', 'match_distance'])
        
    else: None  
    
    result_df = result_df.astype({'score': 'float64', 'match_index': 'int64', 'match_distance': 'float64'})
    return result_df

# データ
t = pd.DataFrame([0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9], columns=['score'])
t.index = list(range(10, len(t)+10))
p = pd.DataFrame([0.7, 0.7, 0.85, 0.85], columns=['score'])
t.index = list(range(100, len(t)+100))
print(len(t), len(p))

methods = ['復元', '非復元']
result_dic = dict()
for method in methods:
    result_dic[method] = matching_score(target=t['score'],
                                        population=p['score'],
                                        method=method)
result_dic

>>> 4 4

>>> {'復元':      score  match_index  match_distance
>>>  100    0.7            0            0.00
>>>  101    0.7            0            0.00
>>>  102    0.8            2            0.05
>>>  103    0.9            2            0.05,
>>>  '非復元':      score  match_index  match_distance
>>>  100    0.7            0            0.00
>>>  101    0.7            1            0.00
>>>  102    0.8            2            0.05
>>>  103    0.9            3            0.05}

